# Franz LISP to Common LISP conversion questions

Tags: common-lisp

I'm reviving an old LISP program from the early 1980s. 
(It's the Nelson-Oppen simplifier, an early proof system.
This version was part of the Ford Pascal-F Verifier,
and was running in Franz LISP in 1982.)  Here's
the entire program:

https://github.com/John-Nagle/pasv/tree/master/src/CPC4

I'm converting the code to run under clisp on Linux,
and need some advice.  Most of the problems are with
macros.

## HUNKSHELL

Hunkshell was a 1970s Stanford SAIL hack to support records with named fields in LISP. I think I've converted this OK; it seems to work.

https://github.com/John-Nagle/pasv/blob/master/src/CPC4/hunkshell.l

The original macro generated more macros as record update functions.
I'm generating `defun`s.  Is there any reason to generate macros?

By the way, look at what I wrote for "CONCAT".  Is there a better way
to do that?

## DEFMAC

More old SAIL macros, to make macro definition easier before `defmacro` became part of the language.

https://github.com/John-Nagle/pasv/blob/master/src/CPC4/defmac.l

I've been struggling with "defunobj".  Here's my CL version, partly converted:

```
  ; This macro works just like defun, except that both the value and the
  ; function-binding of the symbol being defined are set to the function
  ; being defined.  Therefore, after (defunobj f ...), (f ...) calls the
  ; defined function, whereas f evaluates to the function itself.
  ;
(defmacro defunobj (fname args &rest b)
  `(progn 
      (defun ,fname ,args ,b)
      ;;;;(declare (special ,fname)) ;;;; ***declare not allowed here
      (setq ,fname (getd ',fname))))
```

If I made that `declare` a `proclaim`, would that work right?
And what replaces `getd` to get a function pointer?

## SPECIAL

There are lots of `(DECLARE (SPECIAL FOO))` declarations at top
level in this code.  That's not allowed in CL.  Is it 
appropriate to use `(PROCLAIM (SPECIAL FOO))` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Concat

Essentially correct, but indentation is broken (like everywhere else - I suggest Emacs to fix it).

Also, you don't need the [`values`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_values.htm) there.

## defunobj

I suggest [`defparameter`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defpar.htm) instead
of [`setq`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_setq.htm). Generally speaking, before *setting* a variable (with, e.g., `setq`) one should [*establish*](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_e.htm#establish) it (with, e.g., `let` or `defvar`).

[`fdefinition`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_fdefin.htm) is what 
you are looking for instead of `getd`.

I also don't think you are using backquote right:

```
(defmacro defunobj (fname &body body)
  `(progn 
     (defun ,fname ,@body)
     (defparameter ,fname (fdefinition ',fname))))
```

## Special

I think [`defvar` and `defparameter`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defpar.htm)
are better than [`proclaim`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_procla.htm)
[`special`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/d_specia.htm).

PS. Are you aware of the [CR.se](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site?

Comment: VALUES is used to get rid of the second value. For example it then won't be visible in the REPL...

Comment: I know the use of `values`. However, since there is no requirement to return a single value, it is not _necessary_ to strip the second one.

Comment: It's not a requirement, it just makes it more simpler, since the second result of INTERN is not needed for CONCAT and just slightly confusing.

Comment: OK, got "defunobj" straightened out. Thanks. Still having trouble with "defsmac", but I'll post that as a new question.

Comment: @JohnNagle: I suggest that you close the question by [accepting an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/215439)